# Pandas Manipulating Freq for Business Day DateRange

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add a set of common date related columns to my data frame and my approach to building these date columns is off the `.date_range()` pandas method that will have the date range for my dataframe.

While I can use methods like `.index.day` or `.index.weekday_name` for general date columns, I would like to set a business day column based on date_range I constructed, but not sure if I can use the `freq` attribute nickname `'B'` or if I need to create a new date range.

Further, I am hoping to not count those business days based on a list of holiday dates that I have.

Here is my setup:

Holiday table

```
holiday_table = holiday_table.set_index('date')
holiday_table_dates = holiday_table.index.to_list() # ['2019-12-31', etc..]
```

Base Date Table

```
data_date_range = pd.date_range(start=date_range_start, end=date_range_end)

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': data_date_range}).set_index('date')

df['day_index'] = df.index.day

# Weekday Name
df['weekday_name'] = df.index.weekday_name

# Business day
df['business_day'] = data_date_range.freq("B")
```

Error at `df['business_day'] = data_date_range.freq("B")`:

```
---> 13 df['business_day'] = data_date_range.freq("B")
ApplyTypeError: Unhandled type: str
```

Comment: what's the output from `data_date_range.freq("B")`?

Comment: @Yuca the error I mention at the end of my question. `Unhandled type: str`

Comment: what does `data_date_range.index.dtype` return? is it an object?

Comment: what's happening is that `.freq ` is not a method for DatetimeIndex but a parameter for the constructor. Check the docs https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html. I suspect you might want to change the frequency, so check out `asfreq`

Comment: @Chris `AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'index'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think I understand your question now. You are looking to create a a new column of working business days (excluding your custom holidays). In my example i just used the regular US holidays from pandas but you already have your holidays as a list in `holiday_table_dates` but you should still be able to follow the general layout of my example for your specific use. I also used the assumption that you are OK with boolean values for your `business_day` column:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar as h_cal

# sample data
data_date_range = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2019', end='12/31/2019')
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': data_date_range}).set_index('date')
df['day_index'] = df.index.day
# Weekday Name
df['weekday_name'] = df.index.weekday_name

# this is just a sample using US holidays
hday = h_cal().holidays(df.index.min(), df.index.max())
# b is the same date range as bove just with the freq set to business days
b = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2019', end='12/31/2019', freq='B')
# find all the working business day where b is not a holiday
bday = b[~b.isin(hday)]
# create a boolean col where the date index is in your custom business day we just created
df['bday'] = df.index.isin(bday)


            day_index weekday_name   bday
date                                     
2019-01-01          1      Tuesday  False
2019-01-02          2    Wednesday   True
2019-01-03          3     Thursday   True
2019-01-04          4       Friday   True
2019-01-05          5     Saturday  False
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion with my question and you are exactly right! This was very helpful thanks

Comment: Do you mind just linking to the `[~b.isin()]`? I'm not familiar with this method

Comment: @cphill it is called [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing). using `~` just means the opposite so in this case it returns a boolean value `where b is not in hday` you should also read [indexing with isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-with-isin)